# Java nashorn ограничение доступа к системным функциям из JS

Tags: javascript, java, сервер, безопасность

Есть серверное приложение на Java которое запускает пользовательские скрипты на JS (с помощью Nashorn), но тк это все работает на сервере надо ограничить доступ из JS ко всему, кроме того что прокидывается явно.

Как это можно сделать?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Nashorn Sandbox](https://github.com/javadelight/delight-nashorn-sandbox)
Сам не использовал, но это неплохой вариант. По дефолту блокирует все.

Comment: На сколько я знаю по дефолту он ничего не блокирует (по крайней мере он выполнил это `new java.io.File("somefile.file").createNewFile();` и создал новый файл на сервере)

Comment: @ScreamT5 Это касается того что я скинул? Nashorn Sandbox это как раз и есть обертка для выполнения скрипта на стороне сервера. Там все запрещено изначально и только самому можно дать разрешение использовать тот же java.io.FIle. Есть так же защита от зависаний, для бесконечных циклов, ограничения по памяти и прочее. Почитайте

Comment: Извините не заметил

Answer (score 0):

В момент создания движка можно передать ClassFilter

```
new NashornScriptEngineFactory().getScriptEngine(classFilter);
```